# Using pagination to return all Azure AD User info in Python

Tags: python, azure

I'm fetching Azure AD data in a Python script. What I'm interested in is specifically `name`, `email` and `jobtitle` from the `Users` site in Azure.

However, the get request is limited to 100 rows, which I assume has something to do with pagination. Additionally, the `jobtitle` is empty, which has something to do with the app registration.

**QUESTION**

- How do I return more than 100 rows? I'm struggling with the documentation, and I can't find any Python examples on this?

[image]

My code is:

```
import logging
import json
import msal
import requests
import pandas

# Globals
token = None
graphApiVersion = "v1.0"
uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/{v}/{r}"
headers = None

# Functions
def authenticate():
    global token
    global headers
    authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>"
    appID = "<app id>"
    appSecret = "<app secret>"
    scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        appID, authority=authority, client_credential = appSecret)
    token = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)
    if not token:
        token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
    return

def users(Format=True):
    return query(graphApiVersion, "/users?$select=displayName,givenName,jobTitle,email,department", Format)

def query(v, r, Format=True):
    dest = uri.format(v=v, r=r)
    result = requests.get(dest, headers=headers).json()
    if Format:
        print(pandas.json_normalize(result["value"]))
    else:
        return result["value"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `$top` param to Page Microsoft Graph data. And if you use this param, you will get an additional link with name: `@odata.nextLink` to fetch next page data. Details see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

I also did a quick test on my side with your code as below:

```
import logging
import json
import msal
import requests
import pandas

# Globals
token = '<access token>'
graphApiVersion = "v1.0"
uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/{v}/{r}"
headers = None

# Functions

def users(Format=True):
    return query(graphApiVersion, "/users?$select=displayName,givenName,jobTitle,email,department&$top=200", Format)

def query(v, r, Format=True):
    dest = uri.format(v=v, r=r)
    result = requests.get(dest, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}).json()
    if Format:
        print(pandas.json_normalize(result["value"] ))
        print("next page URL:" + result["@odata.nextLink"])
    else:
        return result["value"]

users()
```

It works for me:

[image]